# use regular expressions for validation in java

Tags: java, regex, validation

I want to use regular expressions in java to validate a user input to restrict it to alphanumeric characters and '_'. Also, the first character has to be alphanumeric. But, i have absolutely no knowledge on regular expressions. Any help is higly appreciated.

Thank you Aashish

Comment: Have you tried searching for some tutorial on regex? At least what would match `alphanumeric` character in regex/

Comment: It would be better if you started learning Regex instead of directly asking SO. If you are having any difficulties, then we can help you out. This should get you going. http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Online test tool: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html - will be handy for your practice

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
String regex = "[a-zA-Z0-9]\\w*";

if (input.matches(regex)) {
    // input is OOK
}
```

FYI the regex `\w` is shorthand for "alphanumeric and the underscore", ie `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Answer (score 2):

[Read The Fine Manual](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) (java.util.regex.Pattern)

Comment: Even though things haven't exactly changed for Java's regular expression syntax, linking to version 1.4.2 might not be the most up to date option :)

Comment: Good point. There are a few additions in 1.5 and 1.7. I updated the link because older documentation may contain errors that were fixed later.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this (true - if there are present restricted characters):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9_]");
Matcher m = p.matcher("12A3");
System.out.println(m.find());

m = p.matcher("&*#");
System.out.println(m.find());

>> true
>> false
```

Comment: See regex in @Bohemain answer